What sample size should be reported when using pairwise deletion approach with WLSMV?
I have a question regarding reporting the sample size in an article. The situation is a bit complex, so please allow me to explain below:
I collected data from participants via an online survey. However, due to certain criteria I implemented in the online survey, the sample size varies for five variables. For instance, for the attitude variable at time 1, the sample size is 645, while for other variables at time 2, it is 627 and 485. I analyzed this data in Mplus using the WLSMV estimator, which allows for the use of different sample sizes through pairwise deletion approach. In Mplus, the number of observations is reported as 643. I am unsure which sample size I should report. Should I report the number of observations written in Mplus (643)? Or should I explain the criteria we used for the survey and provide the different sample sizes for each variable (645 for attitude, 627 and 485 for others)?
Thank you so much for your answer!

You should report what happened. There isn't "a sample size"; there are multiple sample sizes.
You might write something like "Data were collected from 645 respondents in the method section".
When you report an analysis, report the same size for that analysis.
Also, consider using multiple imputation instead of listwise deletion.

+1 Both for the answer and the suggestion to do multiple imputation.

Apologies, but I'm unclear why I should state that "data were collected from 645 respondents" and maintain the same size in the analysis section. I opted for pairwise deletion due to using the WLSMV estimator in Mplus, thus avoiding listwise deletion. However, Mplus indicates the number of observations as 643 with pairwise deletion. Notably, 645 represents respondents solely for the attitude scale; other scales feature different respondent counts. Therefore, why should I report 645 as the number of respondents for all scales?

The purpose of a report of a study is to explain what you did and what happened. There aren't super strict rules for exactly what to write, and if there were you should break them when it is clearer. You collected some data from 645 people. Because of missing data, the sample size for each analysis is different. You report the sample size for each analysis.

Mplus provides coverage statistics, for what proportion of the N =643 were used to estimate each (co)variance.  Maybe that is the information you are looking for, about how N varies across summary statistics (in the same analysis).  Regarding the data that were actually analyzed, you could run TYPE=BASIC to estimate and report descriptives using pairwise deletion (if that is how you intend to fit your models).  But I also agree with considering multiple imputation, since pairwise deletion assumes MCAR, whereas MAR can be justified by appropriate auxiliaries in the imputation model.

Doesn't  Mplus uses complete cases only with wlsmv estimation? (It's years since I've used Mplus but this is my memory.)

Thanks for Terrence's suggestions! I've checked the missingness in SPSS using Little's MCAR test, and the missingness in our data is completely distributed at random (MCAR). Based on Terrence's comment, using pairwise deletion appears logical in this case.
Regarding Jeremy Miles' question, yes, Mplus does not use complete cases with WLSMV because Mplus employs pairwise deletion rather than full information maximum likelihood (FIML) with WLSMV estimation method.
